# MongoDB + Grails: How to use the $all operator from Grails

Tags: mongodb, grails, gorm-mongodb

I have a series of tags on an object, and I'd like to query for objects that contains all tags passed as an array.  I know that operators in and inList translate to $in operator in MongoDB, but $in will return any object that contains at least one of the provided tags.  I want objects that contain all provided tags.  Or said another way $in means findAll tags with t1,or t2, or t3, etc.  I want findAll tags with t1 AND t2 AND t3, etc.  Mongodb fortunately supports the $all operator for that.

So how do I execute a query from Grail's GORM MongoDB plugin that will use the $all operator?  Do I have to use the low level API?  If so how do I get the lower level API to return my Domain objects fully populated?

Or Is there a better option for querying than using the $all operator that has better performance and let's me stay within criteria queries of GORM?

Comment: I fear you would have to use the low level API, I do not see there is anything in [MongoQuery](https://github.com/SpringSource/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-mongo/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/mapping/mongo/query/MongoQuery.java) addressing `$all`.

Comment: Is there any better documentation showing examples of using the lower level API, and how to map lower level API into Domain objects?  Is there an alternate query I could use to get the same result without using $all operator?

Comment: You can refer [docs from Mongodb GORM plugin](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/4.%20Low-level%20API.html), if you have not come across it yet.

Comment: Yea I've seen those terrible docs.  I guess I'm on my own again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I feel like I do this just about every couple of weeks, but here I go documenting MongoDB GORM since the authors just don't see it as important.

So $all is not supported.  An alternative query is the following:

```
Photo.findAll {
    and {
       tagList.each { tag ->
          eq( 'tags', tag )
       }
    }
}
```

You can't use ==, but I don't have an explanation for that.  I think I remember reading something about the each closure interfering, but I can't find it or remember where I saw it.  Anyway you have to use eq() method.